# How do I identify what UIImageView was tapped when using the "tap gesture recognition" method?

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a set of 20 buttons that have illustrations on them, so they're images. I researched how to make UIImageView tappable and enabled user interaction on all photos, then added a "tap gesture recognizer."

I want the photos to go to a new view controller. However, all of these buttons lead to a similar area with different content.

To save space in my storyboard, I am trying to make this a singular view controller that calls on a .xib file for 90% of the screen, but based on what button was pressed.

If the user is tapping the "tap gesture recognizer" how can I assign or retrieve a tag or something that I can utilize in my second view controller to fill my view with the .xib file?

Currently my code (excluding imports/other default viewcontroller code) is the following for the first view controller with the range of buttons:

```
@IBOutlet weak var buttonA: UIImageView!
@IBAction func buttonAPressed(_ sender: buttonA) {
}
```

I want to be able to specify the image tapped as the sender, then carry this over to the second viewcontroller to determine the .xib file. I don't think I can do this because the image isn't the sender, "Tap Gesture Recognition" is.

As simple as it is, Xcode is giving me an error for putting anything put "Any" in the sender area.

How can I resolve this? Or better yet, how can I identify what UIImageView was tapped and accomplish my goals swifter?

Comment: Show your code for creating and applying the tap gesture.

Comment: To create an apply the tap gesture, I went into the main.storyboard and searched for "tap gesture" then dragged it onto the photo I wanted to interact with. It didn't add anything to my viewcontroller, but I added:

@IBAction func buttonAPressed(_ sender: buttonA) {
}

I would fill in more fields in this function, but I already have an error with the sender field and can't figure out anything but "Any"

Comment: The action of a tap gesture should look like `@IBAction func someName(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {`.

Comment: See duplicate.  The gesture recognizer has a `view` property which is the view it is attached to.  In your case, you could do `guard let imageView = sender.view as? UIImageView else { return }`.